# My husband keeps dying

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-comes-alive

I'm on peaceful creative mode and my husband is in full diamond armor. However, my husband keeps on dying. He's not being attacked by anything either - he just drops dead?

I've done everything I can think of but every time I remarry he keeps on dying.

Anyone know how to prevent that from happening?

Comment: "My husband keeps on dying" Add that title to the list of great out-of-context phrases...

Answer (score 2):

It could just be a glitch. If he is dying on a specific block, most likely there is a functional problem with the world.

Comment: More in formation would be helpful. And what version are you playing?